# Rich Text Editor with Gmail style spell check

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, gmail

I am after a JavaScript Rich Text Editor that supports highlighting words and triggering events when those highlighted words are clicked, like what Gmail does when in spellcheck mode.

I will need to heavily customize any existing solution, so something that is easy to extend would be ideal. Currently I am leaning towards [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Comment: any ideas about spell check integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richtextbox or HTML?

If it is HTML, then you should stick with [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).  :

- It's (very) easy to integrate
- It works across browsers
- The toolbars were easy to modify
- Wordpress uses it!

For what its worth, we also looked at [FCKEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/) but preferred TinyMCE

**UPDATE:**  While some users wanted it, spell checking has never been on the "essentials" list.  It has always been quicker / cheaper for us to teach the handful of users how to use the spell checking features of [IE](http://www.iespell.com/), [Firefox](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-a-Spell-Checker-Into-Firefox) or [Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95604) instead of putting it in the editor.

Imagine trying to code the [3 been soup](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9139295/Ride_the_Wave_Hands_On_With_Google_Wave_Preview) example!!!

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE seems to be the best one these days. You might want to take a look at [FCKEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/) and [HTMLArea](http://www.htmlarea.com/) as well. You can find a list of such WYSIWYG HTML editors [here](http://www.cmsreview.com/WYSIWYG/OpenSource/directory.html).